# How to install system_timer gem on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7, rubygems

I got problem 
"Processing environment.rb: Pre Initialisation Phase (using rails 2.3.5)"
"Processing environment.rb: Main Initialisation Phase"
C:/Ruby/bin/rake: No such file or directory - svnversion
[memcache-client] Could not load SystemTimer gem, falling back to Ruby's slower/unsafe timeout library: no such file to
load -- system_timer
rake aborted!

## unable to find server during initialization.

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
I dunno how to install this gem, because when i exec gem install system_timer i receiving:
"Processing environment.rb: Pre Initialisation Phase (using rails 2.3.5)"
"Processing environment.rb: Main Initialisation Phase"
C:/Ruby/bin/rake: No such file or directory - svnversion
[memcache-client] Could not load SystemTimer gem, falling back to Ruby's slower/unsafe timeout library: no such file to
load -- system_timer
rake aborted!

## unable to find server during initialization.

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'

Anybody, help please!

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't install system_timer in Windows system. If you see on [gem page](http://systemtimer.rubyforge.org/) in requirement, you can see

> SystemTimer  only works on UNIX
>   platforms (Mac OS X, Linux, Solaris,
>   BSD, …). You can install the gem on
>   Microsoft Windows, but you will only
>   get a convenience shell wrapping a
>   simple call to timeout.rb under the
>   cover.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try install this gem ?

```
gem install system_timer
```

Comment: "Processing environment.rb: Pre Initialisation Phase (using rails 2.3.5)" "Processing environment.rb: Main Initialisation Phase" C:/Ruby/bin/rake: No such file or directory - svnversion [memcache-client] Could not load SystemTimer gem, falling back to Ruby's slower/unsafe timeout library: no such file to load -- system_timer rake aborted!

unable to find server during initialization.
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'

Comment: Ok, your formating is bad so I don't understand that error becomes with installing system_timer.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails < 3:

environnement.rb

```
config.gem "SystemTimer", :lib => "system_timer"
```